# PHP Array Pagination with $_GET

Tags: php, pagination

I have sample array here: `http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=rU287x69` and I want it to have a pagination with `2 result per page`.

The pagination will be based from the url parameter (`$_GET['page']`)

My array has `7 objects`. So the `max` page will be `4` since it will display `2 per page`.

I already code it but the problem is even if the page is out of number.

Ex. `?page=5` there's still a result which is from `page 4`

```
    $page_page = 2;
    $page = ! empty( $_GET['page'] ) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1;
    $total = count($apps);
    $totalPages = ceil( $total/ $page_page );
    $page = max($page, 1);
    $page = min($page, $totalPages);
    $offset = ($page - 1) * $page_page;
    if( $offset < 0 ) $offset = 0;

    $apps = array_slice( $apps, $offset, $page_page );
    print_r($apps);
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is incorrect.

```
//For your example: ?page=5
$page_page = 2;    
$page = ! empty( $_GET['page'] ) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1;   // 5
$total = count($apps);                                        // 7
$totalPages = ceil( $total/ $page_page );                     // 4
$page = max($page, 1);                                        // 5 (correct)
$page = min($page, $totalPages);                              // 4 (incorrect)
$offset = ($page - 1) * $page_page;                           // 6 (incorrect)
```

Your offset is 6, so returning record number 7.

If you remove these 2 lines:

```
$page = max($page, 1);    
$page = min($page, $totalPages);
```

The rest of your logic will then work.

```
?page=1   $offset = (1-1)*2    //0
?page=2   $offset = (2-1)*2    //2
?page=3   $offset = (3-1)*2    //4
?page=4   $offset = (4-1)*2    //6 - records 7 and 8
?page=5   $offset = (5-1)*2    //8 - no records
```

If you need this value for the pagination loop, either rename it or move it below $offset.

Comment: However, those two lines offers good validation unless an error is shown when page is not correct